# How to make Transform.scale widget on the top in children of Wrap, Column, etc?

Tags: flutter

The target widget that will change the scale from 1.0 to 1.X was covered by the next widget.
You can see an example from this image. Box 29 covers boxes these numbers lower than 29 (0, 1, 2, and 28) and is covered by boxes that numbers more than 29 (30, 56, 57, and 58).
[image]

I want to make the target box(29) on the top of these widgets. How to do that?

code example:

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({super.key});

  @override
  State<Example> createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  Color getRandomColor(int index) {
    final random = Random();
    final r = random.nextInt(256);
    final g = random.nextInt(256);
    final b = random.nextInt(256);

    return Color.fromARGB(255, r, g, b);
  }

  Widget widgetBuilder(int index) {
    final isHover = Rx(false); //Using state management with GetX.
    final color = getRandomColor(index);
    final borderColor = getRandomColor(index);
    return InkWell(
      onHover: (value) => isHover.value = value,
      onTap: () {},
      child: Obx(
        () => Transform.scale(
          scale: isHover.value ? 1.5 : 1,
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: color,
              border: Border.all(color: borderColor, width: 1),
            ),
            child: Text(index.toString()),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  late final itemList = [for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) widgetBuilder(i)];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Wrap(
        spacing: 10,
        runSpacing: 10,
        children: itemList,
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment, I fix it by using the `Stack` widget.
The `Wrap` widget on top of the stack will show all containers with transparent color. When a container is hovered, this container with a transparent color will change scale to big and color to the real value.

[image]

Example code:
***This transparent color concept can be used for any responsive widget. But using the `SizedBox` widget with the same size in this case is enough***

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({super.key});

  @override
  State<Example> createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  Color getRandomColor(int index) {
    final random = Random();
    final r = random.nextInt(256);
    final g = random.nextInt(256);
    final b = random.nextInt(256);

    return Color.fromARGB(255, r, g, b);
  }

  Widget widgetBuilder({required bool isOnTop, required int index, required Color bgColor, required Color borderColor}) {
    const width = 50.0;
    const height = 50.0;

    final boxWidget = Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      width: width,
      height: height,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: bgColor,
        border: Border.all(color: borderColor, width: 1),
      ),
      child: Text(index.toString()),
    );

    if (isOnTop) {
      final isHover = Rx(false); //Using state management with GetX.
      return InkWell(
        onHover: (value) => isHover.value = value,
        onTap: () {},
        child: Obx(
          () => Transform.scale(
            scale: isHover.value ? 2 : 1,
            child: isHover.value ? boxWidget : SizedBox(width: width, height: height),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return boxWidget;
  }

  late final itemList = <Widget>[];
  late final itemOnTopList = <Widget>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      final bgColor = getRandomColor(i);
      final borderColor = getRandomColor(i);
      itemList.add(widgetBuilder(isOnTop: false, index: i, bgColor: bgColor, borderColor: borderColor));
      itemOnTopList.add(widgetBuilder(isOnTop: true, index: i, bgColor: bgColor, borderColor: borderColor));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Wrap(spacing: 10, runSpacing: 10, children: itemList),
          Wrap(spacing: 10, runSpacing: 10, children: itemOnTopList),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

I hope that someone can find a solution that is better than this.